# Should the information from tags be present in the question body?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example when I'm asking a question about regex, should the question body contain information like what language I'm using or is a tag indicating that enough?

I saw [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7146) question over on the RPG meta with which I agree, but I want to see if the SO community thinks otherwise.

Comment: I like one part of that linked answer: *"Tags are for searching and sorting"*. Indeed. That is basically the kicker: people should not have to read the question to learn what language it is about, that should have been clear even before the question is opened.

Comment: In the case of regex, wouldn't the language be important, since some flags or use cases will work differently between languages? Even though some aspects should be language-agnostic

Answer (score 3):

The tag itself is enough.

There is no need to add the tag itself to the question's body, also.

Comment: And also not to the question's title ;)